# How to solve The named parameter 'padding' isn't defined. The named parameter 'shape' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to solve this error The named parameter 'padding' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'padding'.and The named parameter 'shape' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'shape'. Show one can help me?

This is my code

```
 ElevatedButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0), // Error
    onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
    pageContent =
    new PatientDetailsProfilePage(
    token: widget.token,
    fullName: widget.fullName,
    apiEndPoint: widget.apiEndPoint,
    userUID: widget.userUID,
     patientProfile:
     widget.patientProfile);
    });
   },
    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder( // Error
     borderRadius:
     new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
     ),
    child: new Text('Profile',
    style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ElevatedButton.styleFrom`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/styleFrom.html)

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {
     .....
  },

),
```